# Whats the difference between metal and plastic insulation support fixings?

Tags: insulation

I am putting 30mm of fibre insulation on a party wall and then covering it with 12.5mm soundbloc plasterboard which will then be skimmed. Does it matter whether I use plastic or metal insulation support fixings and do they both skim over ok?